# react-chatbot-kit on web application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to use react-chatbot-kit on a plain html/css/js website, using the webpack bundle which compiles fine. However, the popup does not show on the web page. Have tried the same with react-simple-chatbot and it works fine. It does not work for the react-chatbot-kit.

Would appreciate help in getting it resolved. Thanks in advance!

Cheers

The code in index.js using the react-chatbot-kit is pasted below.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Chatbot from 'react-chatbot-kit';
import ActionProvider from './components/react-chatbot-kit/ActionProvider';
import MessageParser from './components/react-chatbot-kit/MessageParser';
import config from './components/react-chatbot-kit/config';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';

const chatwindowconfig ={
    width: "350px",
    height: "500px",
    floating: true,
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <h1>This is the bundle from React!</h1>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <ChatBot
                    config={config} 
                    MessageParser={MessageParser} 
                    ActionProvider={ActionProvider}
                    {...chatwindowconfig}
            />
        </ThemeProvider>

    </div>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```